# Problem with persian-bib package

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi, xepersian

I have a document where the main language should be English with only some Arabic text.
In my references I have English as well as Arabic references.
The main direction of the document should be from left to right, except Arabic text.
The persian-bib package is working nicely but I have only one problem:
I have `\begin{latin}` after `\begin{document}` and `\end{latin}` before `\end{document}` and inbetween I use `\rl{some arabic text}` but for the references I have to add `\rl{}` for all entries of a bibtex reference to show the Arabic text and also the text is still aligned from left to right because the environment as a whole is still latin. 
Thus the reference appears like this:

برنامج .عزيزة مبارك العلوني، مريم عبد الرحمن السهلي، مهرة فارس المطيري [ 1
تعليمي الكتروني في تنمیة بعض من مهارات الاستعداد للقراءة لدى أطفال
2011 ,رسالة ماجستير غير منشورة .ما قبل المدرسة

Where the text is truncated in a wrong way, making fields overlap and text discontinue because of alignment.
Please tell me what I can do to solve my problem.

Comment: Please send me an email. <vafakhlg at googlemail.com>